# Spring boot compile jsp error after a week

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsp, compiler-errors

I have a spring boot application with jsp, when I start this application and access from chrome, everything is ok. But after a week later, when I access a page that I never access before, there is an error :

```
An error occurred at line: [45] in the jsp file: [/WEB-INF/views/includes/list.jsp]
org.apache.jsp.tag.web.locale_tag cannot be resolved to a type
42: <script src="${ctx}/static/javascript/jquery.ztree.all-3.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
43: <script src="${ctx}/static/javascript/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
44: <script src="${ctx}/static/javascript/i18n/messages.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
45: <script src="${ctx}/static/javascript/i18n/messages_<tags:locale/>.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
46: <script src="${ctx}/static/javascript/base64.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
47: <script src="${ctx}/static/javascript/jquery.dateFormat-1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
48: <script src="${ctx}/static/javascript/icheck.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I restart the application and access this page again, no error.

I have upgrade spring boot to 2.1.4, not work.
I have update jdk from 1.8 to jdk10 and jdk12, not work.

config properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.mvc.view.exposeContextBeansAsAttributes=true
```

jsp tag files on path /META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/tags

I expected that after application start, there is no error any time user access any page.

Comment: Got an idea, it may be /tmp folder clear by server, I will add server.tomcat.basedir and try again.

Comment: can you check the answer? Did you solve it? If yes, can you update your answer so people can know how to fix it? @Sun Zhen

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: This is the right answer. I also add "context.setResources(new ExtractingRoot())" to avoid sometime block jsp compile on custom TomcatServletWebServerFactory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the tomcat folder will be the tmp folder and it will be cleaned after sometime.

The OS is the one cleaning the folder.

To avoid this problem, try setting the "server.tomcat.basedir=/your/folder" to a valid non-temp directory in the server. This will avoid the cleanup.